# How do I enable the console in Supertux2 v0.5.1 on Debian?

Tags: linux, supertux

I installed Supertux2 from the Debian stretch/stable repositories. According to `supertux2 --version`, it's v0.5.1, but according to `man supertux2`, it's v0.3.2-SVN. Anyway. According to [the documentation](http://supertux.lethargik.org/wiki/Console), I should be able to create the `~/.supertux2/config` file and populate it with `(console #t)` to enable the console. Once I do that, however, pressing `^` inside the game doesn't bring up the console...

Plus, if I run `supertux2 --console` from the terminal, it says `Error: Unknown option '--console''.` *even though the `--console` option is documented in the man page*.

How do I enable the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The man page may be outdated. The help page (`supertux2 --help`) lists the correct option: `supertux2 --developer`.